# three.js - Cannot call method 'loadTexture' of undefined

Tags: loading, textures, three.js, repeat

Sorry for my English.
I've got a problem while working with Three.js.
In every example of loading a texture I see this code:

```
var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "obj/textures/textures38.jpg" );
    map.wrapS   = map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    map.repeat.set( 3, 3 );
```

Could you tell me, why can i get messages like

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadTexture' of undefined
```

---

This works well:

```
var material=new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:16777215,map:ImageUtils.loadTexture("obj/textures/textures38.jpg")});
```

P.S. Three.js version that I currently use is not last

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> P.S. Three.js version that I currently use is not last

You just answered your own question. Probably that version didn't have `ImageUtils` namespaced yet. Always recommended using the latest version.

Comment: @mdroob Thanks. Couldn't you advise - should I use a BinaryLoader instead of old `loader.loadbinary` function ?

Comment: cause i'm getting some errors in `JSON.parse` region of the library while changing the code to new one

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
import { BasisTextureLoader } from './jsm/loaders.basisTexureLoader.js'; 
const loadersvariable = BasisTextureLoader.load("img.jpg");
```

You need to change permissions on the folder and file or you will get a `403 forbidden` error. Point the import path to the dependency to the `three.js` loader folder but it all has to be together cause all the file link together then you have to call the variable from the file for it to be live without calling the variable from the file you get `uncaught referenceError: BasisTextureLoader is not defined`

or you can do

```
<script type="module"> import { TextureLoader } from './src/loaders/TextureLoader.js';
const imagevariablename = new Textureloader.load("image.jpg");
also the displacementmap of examples folder in three.js has a working texture.loader already to copy
```